# How to access file accessed from server.js and display it in the html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, express

I am creating a youtube video downloader with express, html, javascript and later on I want to switch to vue.js.

This is my code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Own Youtube downloader</h1>
    <input class="URL-input" type="text" placeholder="enter...">
    <button class="convert-button">Convert</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.js

```
var convertBtn = document.querySelector(".convert-button");
var URLinput = document.querySelector(".URL-input");

convertBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("URL : ${URLinput.value}");
  sendURL(URLinput.value);
});

function sendURL(URL) {
  window.location.href = `http://localhost:4000/download?URL=${URL}`;
}
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is working at port 4000 !!");
});
app.get("/download", (req, res) => {
  var URL = req.query.URL;

  res.header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="video.mp4');

  ytdl(URL, {
    format: "mp4",
  }).pipe(res);
});
```

Right now, everything works fine.
**I just want to implement the functionality so you can see the youtube video on the frontend in the html.**

Does anyone know how to implement this functionality?

PS: I rather don't use a database, only node and express for now

Comment: You could use a video tag but why don't you just embed the video from YouTube in the first place instead of downloading and forwarding it? https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: Well I could, but I rather don't see the youtube logo if that is possible?

Comment: If you add `?modestbranding=1` to the Embed URL you get only a text "YouTube" when the video is paused and you view the title, if I remember correctly. Removing it entirely would likely be against YouTube's terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

on server.js use

```
app.get("/download/:URL", (req, res) =>  {
var URL = req.params.URL;
res.header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment; filename="video.mp4');
ytdl(URL, {
    format: "mp4",
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

and main file, use

```
document.getElementById('video').src=`localhost:8080/download/${URL}`;
```

And in html file add

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
   
</video>
```

Comment: But how will I see the video in the html now? The downloader already works.

Comment: do you want to use video tag to show video in your html file

Comment: Exactly that is what i want to do

Comment: Then add video tag to your html and its src to `localhost:8080/download/${URL}`. You can do so by using javascript.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it with some code?

Comment: Okay. I will edit my answer

Comment: I appreciate it

Comment: I have one question, should I replace code in the server.js or should I just add that piece of code

Comment: Replace only the part which i edited... Not entirely

Comment: It doesn't work, I think it is because it is not on localhost:8080, my frontend runs at http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html and backend at localhost:4000

Comment: The use 127.0.0.1:5500/download/${URL}

Comment: I get errors… Do you know how to solve them

Comment: It says Cannot GET /download

Comment: And it appears since I changed the server.js code with your snippet

Comment: I'm outside right now. I'll do it later